# Search DynamoDB column for a specific string using DynamoDBMapper

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

I am using DynamoDBMapper to scan a a table, specifically a column named "title". I should be returned a list of blogs that contains a string passed into the scanExpression. This is code I wrote about a year and a half ago which I remember working. Maybe something has been updated since?

Thanks!

```
public List<BlogDetailsEntity> searchBlogs(String query) {
          DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
          scanExpression.addFilterCondition("title", new Condition()
                  .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.CONTAINS)
                  .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(query.toLowerCase())));
          return dynamoDBMapper.scan(BlogDetailsEntity.class, scanExpression);
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not best practice anymore. Java V1 and this mapper should be replaced with **AWS SDK  for Java V2**.

To get the latest code for AWS, always refer to the new **AWS Code Library** here.

[Code examples for DynamoDB using AWS SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/dynamodb_code_examples.html)

To filter a column using the [V2 enhanced client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html) (a replacement for DynamoDBMapper), you can use **DynamoDbEnhancedClient**. For example, assume you want to scan a table to get all Closed items on a column named **archive**.

[image]

You can use code like this.

```
 // Get Open items from the DynamoDB table.
    public List<WorkItem> getOpenItems() {

        // Create a DynamoDbEnhancedClient.
        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
            .dynamoDbClient(getClient())
            .build();

        try{
            // Create a DynamoDbTable object.
            DynamoDbTable<Work> table = enhancedClient.table("Work", TableSchema.fromBean(Work.class));
            AttributeValue attr = AttributeValue.builder()
                .s("Open")
                .build();

            Map<String, AttributeValue> myMap = new HashMap<>();
            myMap.put(":val1",attr);

            Map<String, String> myExMap = new HashMap<>();
            myExMap.put("#archive", "archive");

            // Set the Expression so only Closed items are queried from the Work table.
            Expression expression = Expression.builder()
                .expressionValues(myMap)
                .expressionNames(myExMap)
                .expression("#archive = :val1")
                .build();

            ScanEnhancedRequest enhancedRequest = ScanEnhancedRequest.builder()
                .filterExpression(expression)
                .limit(15)
                .build();

            // Scan items.
            Iterator<Work> results = table.scan(enhancedRequest).items().iterator();
            WorkItem workItem ;
            ArrayList<WorkItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

            while (results.hasNext()) {
                workItem = new WorkItem();
                Work work = results.next();
                workItem.setName(work.getName());
                workItem.setGuide(work.getGuide());
                workItem.setDescription(work.getDescription());
                workItem.setStatus(work.getStatus());
                workItem.setDate(work.getDate());
                workItem.setId(work.getId());

                // Push the workItem to the list.
                itemList.add(workItem);
            }
            return itemList;

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You can find a complete **AWS end to end developer tutorial** that teaches you how to use this code to display Amazon DynamoDB items in a React client app. For example, this illustration shows **Closed** items.

[image]

This complete doc can be found in the code lib here:

[Create an Amazon Relational Database Service item tracker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/dynamodb_example_cross_DynamoDBDataTracker_section.html)